# Formatting LocalDate in Java

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

I defined the following format in Java :

```
//define format of YYYYMMDD
private final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
```

My application fetches a certain date from the calendar:

```
LocalDate localDate = fetchDate(); // fetch date in format "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

I want to store an additional two dates in format of `dtf`. The `startOfMonth` and `endOfMonth` of the given `localDate`.

E.g. if `localDate` is `"2019-12-12"` I want to create the following two variables -

```
String startOfMonth = "20191201";
String endOfMonth = "20191231";
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LocalDate atStartOfMonth = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate atEndOfMonth = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

And then you format those local dates the way you want to (i.e. with your `dtf` formatter)